# C++ how to append char and integer to string

Tags: c++, string, vector, integer, char

how to append char and integer to string in C++ programmin

for example,

```
int value_of_int = 100;
char value_of_char[20] = "HELLO";
string result_line;

result_line << value_of_int;
result_line << value_of_char;

vector<string> result_set;
result_set.push_back(result_line);
```

the value of int and char will be changed and want to save `vector<string>.`

Comment: Please reformulate your question and add (a lot) more details. It is unclear (at least to me) what you intend to achieve.

Comment: Please *ask a question*.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an `ostringstream`:

```
int value_of_int = 100;
char value_of_char[20] = "HELLO";
std::ostringstream result_line; // #include <sstream>

result_line << value_of_int << value_of_char;

vector<string> result_set;
result_set.push_back(result_line.str());
```